# Why isn't my selenium chromedriver showing a dropdown menu?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver with Chrome in Python. I initialize the driver as follows:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), 'chromedriver'))

driver.get("https://www.macys.com")
```

I then attempt to get the "SHOP BY DEPARTMENT" menu at the top left to display. I first try hovering my mouse over the menu. In normal Chrome, this works, but in the browser opened by Selenium, the menu doesn't show up.

[image: image showing shop by department menu closed]

I then try hovering through code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

menu = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("redesign-header-radical-category-dropdown")[0]
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).perform()
```

Still, the menu doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

One weird thing - I *can* see the dropdown menu for the shopping bag in the top right.
[image: image showing shopping bag]

Comment: Looks like it is frozen in automation window, I have tried with chrome and firefox, it did not work in both of them

Comment: selenium needs to be able to see it on the page. So you have to click on it and wait for the element to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a wait.
Also I see you are missing `build()` in building the Actions action.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
menu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.redesign-header-radical-category-dropdown')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).build().perform()
```

Comment: no , build is not mandatory, it's perform that fired up  events from queue which are store in actionchain.

Comment: Maybe, I will not argue. But wait looks to be a cause of the problem.

Comment: no looks to be application issue, i tried with FF, chrome.. neither worked

Comment: Tried this, no change in behavior. Any other ideas?

Comment: In case it's something from the application side that happens for automated browsers as cruisepandey says I can't help without having to debug it, but I can't do that, I'm sorry.